# deleting ArrayList element which is equal to n

Tags: java, arraylist

```
for (int cell: locations){ // locations is a ArrayList of integers
        if (guess == cell) {
            result = "hit";
            //locations.set(cell, null);
            numOfHits++;
            break;
        }
    }
```

my problem is to play minesweeper with computer and in for loop i am checking each of targets locations, so after i checked one of them i want to not to check again it one more time!! 
I tried to remove but ArrayList elemet which is equal to cell but when input is the same index again it brings error. And i tried to set checked one to null but it is buggy also!!!

Comment: The trick is to read the error message. And to google for it if you don't understand it. And to post it if you don't find anything. And to post the code that is causing the error.

Comment: Man i know what error it is, but i don't know how to deal with it!!!

Comment: You know it, but we don't, because you didn't tell us about it. Isn't that obvious? You're asking us to explain a bug in code you didn't post, and which causes an exception you didn't post either.

Comment: @halu So let us know what error it is, so we could help. And what's with the '!!!'?

Answer (score 1):

You're better off not trying to manually modify the contents of an `ArrayList`.
When you set a specific index to null on an `ArrayList<Integer>`, you aren't actually removing the element.  You are leaving that element in place, but with a value of `null`:

```
    ArrayList<Integer> locations = new ArrayList<>();
    locations.add(1);
    locations.add(2);
    System.out.println(locations); // [1, 2]
    locations.set(0, null);
    System.out.println(locations); // [null, 2]
```

When you later try to access the index you set to `null`, you're likely getting a `NullPointerException` when you try to unbox the `null` into an `int`:

```
    int i = locations.get(0); // throws NPE trying to convert null to int
```

Instead of using a for-each loop use an `Iterator`, which can safely modify the contents of a data structure while traversing it:

```
    Iterator<Integer> itr = locations.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        int cell = itr.next();
        if (guess == cell) {
            result = "hit";
            itr.remove();
            numOfHits++;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: ok, thanks. As i am new to java and programming i don't know what iterator but i will google it

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the element from the ArrayList. But note that it would decrement the index of all the following elements (i.e. the previous (i+1)'th element would become the new i'th element), so you have to decrement the loop index to account for that. Actually, if you are breaking from the loop after removing the item, it doesn't matter if you decrement the index or not.

```
    for (int i=0; i<locations.size();i++){
        int cell = locations.get(i);
        if (guess == cell) {
            result = "hit";
            locations.remove(i);
            i--; // this only matters if you continue iterating over the list
            numOfHits++;
            break;
        }
    }
```